# How can I extract an attachment from the email body (encoded as base64)

Tags: email, base64

How can I extract attachments from an email when they arrive encoded in the body of the email like this:

```
------ =_NEXTPART_FORMSCAPE_MAIL_message101122101615
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="MyFile_hasalongish
     filename_22-NOV-2010.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyFile_hasalongishfilename_22-NOV-2010.pdf"
Content-Description: MyFile_hasalongishfilename_22-NOV-2010.pdf

JVBEDi0xLjMKJcfsj6IKNSAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNiAwIFIvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0
ZFRGVSdsfSDF43N0cmVhbQp4nJ0b23IVN/LdXzG1D7vnbOUMo9tISiWpBduAN2CMbZJN
[...]
OUIwOEYxRDcyRjkwRDAxRUU1QzBDMjhEM0Y+XQo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKMTMwNDQKJSVF
T0YK
------ =_NEXTPART_FORMSCAPE_MAIL_message101122101615--
```

Comment: You'll need to find a UUDECODE tool to convert the ASCII to a valid file.

Comment: On what operating system, or with what mail architecture (local unix delivery, fetchmail, Thunderbird, Outlook, ...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the email to a text file with the extension `.uue` and extract the attachment with a de-archiver.

Answer (score 21):

Copy only the base64 encoded text into a new text file `foo.txt`.

```
base64 --decode foo.txt > bar.pdf
```

I just decoded a base64 stream that had an extra bit on the end that I had to remove. It looked like this: `--=_59494bda030d4629113a60ff13935d81--`. Before I removed it I got the error: `Invalid character in input stream.` After I deleted it, no decoding errors and it opened just fine.

Comment: Also if  facing `invalid input` errors, some might find useful to add `--ignore-garbage` (or just `-i`) flag

Comment: The @deevee tip worked like a charm to me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recover the file using a base64 decoder and copying only the actual text that was the encoded attachment, not any of the surrounding header/footer stuff.